# How to resize elements in a ragged tensor in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to resize every element in a ragged tensor. For example, if I have a ragged tensor of various sized images, how can I resize each one so that the dimensions are the same?

For example,

```
digits = tf.ragged.constant([np.zeros((1,60,60,1)), np.zeros((1,46,75,1))])
resize_lambda = lambda x: tf.image.resize(x, (60,60))
res = tf.ragged.map_flat_values(resize_lambda, digits)
```

I wish res to be a tensor of shape (2,60,60,1). How can I achieve this?

To clarify, this would be useful if within a custom layer we wanted to slice or crop sections from a single image to batch for inference in the next layer. In my case, I am attempting to combine two models (a model to segment an image into multiple cropped images of varying size and a classifier to predict each sub-image). I am also using tf 2.0

Comment: Why would you place the images inside a RaggedTensor, if you want to reshape them all to the same shape? RaggedTensors are essentially used to save tensors with different shapes. I would suggest to reshape your images using tf.image.resize and use normal tensors instead of RaggedTensors.

Comment: @Thomas I hope I clarified my intent in my recent edit. Essentially, the ragged tensor is a product of a segmenting model that predicts regions of interest, each of which need to be classified. So, if I can resize each element, then I can pass forward to the next model for batch inference on the set of regions... I am just trying to combine two trained models to simplify production code.

Comment: @leonard Are you using TF2 or TF1?

Comment: @thushv89 I am using 2.0

Comment: @leonard I am currently trying to solve a similar problem. I have a bunch of coordinates, which I need to crop out subimages as well, to later run through a separatly classifier. Perhaps we can help one another, could you add me on LinkedIn: Thomas Vervenne?

Comment: @leonard did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do the following.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
digits = tf.ragged.constant([np.zeros((1,60,60,1)), np.zeros((1,46,75,1))])

res = tf.concat(
   [tf.image.resize(digits[i].to_tensor(), (60,60)) for i in tf.range(digits.nrows())], 
   axis=0)
```